# AppWidget stopped working in several devices

Tags: android, android-pendingintent, android-appwidget

I have an android app which is basically an appwidget for rain detection in the southeast of Brazil. It has been working fine since its launch, however suddenly it stoppped working in several devices.

The appwidget simply does not respond anymore to any touches. It works fine on my phone (Lenovo K6 with AOSP extended), but I received reports from many Motorola/Samsung phones which the widget simply froze. Restarting the device or reinstalling the app does not solve.

Since I cannot reproduce the problem on my phone or in the emulator, it became a headache to me to find the problem source. One important thing to say is that the widget stopped working after I changed the targetSdkVersion to 26, as it was requested by Google last year. I don't know if it is related, but it happened nearly the same time.

I'm attaching below the parts of my widget class which handles updating and setting the intents for the buttons (I've omitted parts with /* ... */, as the code would be too lengthy and confusing here):

```
public class RadarWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {
    private static int noOfIntents = 4;

    /* ... */

    static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int appWidgetId) {
        RadarWidget.updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId, null, null, null, null);
    }

    static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int appWidgetId, Bitmap overlay, Bitmap background, String dateTimeString, String title) {
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.radar_widget);

        /* ... (read shared preferences) */

        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.radarwidget_syncbutton,
                getSyncPendingIntent(context, appWidgetId));
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.radarwidget_gpsbutton,
                getToggleGPSPendingIntent(context, appWidgetId));
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.radarwidget_rewbutton,
                getGoBackPendingIntent(context, appWidgetId));
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.radarwidget_rewibutton,
                getGoBackPendingIntent(context, appWidgetId));
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.radarwidget_ffbutton,
                getGoForwardPendingIntent(context, appWidgetId));
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.radarwidget_ffibutton,
                getGoForwardPendingIntent(context, appWidgetId));

        /* ... (set texts, images, etc. on the widget) */

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        /* If received intent is one of ours (for widget update), use our logic */
        if (intent.getAction().equals("com.comodo.weatherpal.ACTION_UPDATE_WIDGET")) {
            /* ... (get extras from intent) */

            AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);

            if (widgetId != -1) {
                /* ... (perform some logic according to received extras, update shared preferences) */

                RadarWidget.updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, widgetId, null, null,
                        context.getString(R.string.radarwidget_loadinglabel), null);
            }
        }
        /* Received intent is not one of ours for widget updating, send it to super */
        else {
            super.onReceive(context, intent);
        }
    }

    static PendingIntent getSyncPendingIntent(Context context, int widgetId) {
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.comodo.weatherpal.ACTION_UPDATE_WIDGET");
        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, widgetId);
        intent.putExtra("sync", true);
        return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, widgetId * noOfIntents, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    }

    static PendingIntent getToggleGPSPendingIntent(Context context, int widgetId) {
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.comodo.weatherpal.ACTION_UPDATE_WIDGET");
        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, widgetId);
        intent.putExtra("toggleGPS", true);
        return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, widgetId * noOfIntents + 1, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    }

    static PendingIntent getGoBackPendingIntent(Context context, int widgetId) {
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.comodo.weatherpal.ACTION_UPDATE_WIDGET");
        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, widgetId);
        intent.putExtra("goBack", true);
        return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, widgetId * noOfIntents + 2, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    }

    static PendingIntent getGoForwardPendingIntent(Context context, int widgetId) {
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.comodo.weatherpal.ACTION_UPDATE_WIDGET");
        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, widgetId);
        intent.putExtra("goForward", true);
        return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, widgetId * noOfIntents + 3, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    }
}
```

I have been talking with one of the affected users, I created a specific test version where I checked if any exception was raised in the updateAppWidget method but apparently nothing is raised.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Show your stacktrace of exception.

Comment: @DmitroIvanov there won't be any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're probably not testing with a device running Oreo.

Oreo introduced [severe limitations](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#broadcasts) on implicit broadcasts (no component or package set on the Intent). If you have a device running Oreo and your app is targeting Oreo, you'll hit these limits. If your app is targeting Nougat and/or you're running Nougat or lower, you won't notice them.

It should be pretty easy for you to get around this.

When you construct your wrapped Intents, use this instead:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, RadarWidget.class);
intent.setAction("com.comodo.weatherpal.ACTION_UPDATE_WIDGET");
```

The rest of the code can remain the same. This simply makes sure that the Intent is explicitly targeting your RadarWidget class, so Android won't block it from executing.

Comment: That indeed solved my problem. Gee that was easy. Thank you!